# Android image editor intent: retrieving saved file location

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using the ACTION_EDIT intent to launch the Android image editor in order to edit an image:

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
editIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
```

When launching the intent with result, how do I retrieve the path of the edited / saved image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am using the ACTION_EDIT intent to launch the Android image editor in order to edit an image

Bear in mind that Android does not have an image editor. Some Android devices might ship with an image editor, and some users may have installed an image editor off of the Play Store or other distribution channels.

Also, since you know what the MIME type is of `uri`, you will have better results if you put the real MIME type into your `Intent`.

> When launching the intent with result, how do I retrieve the path of the edited / saved image?

First, `ACTION_EDIT` does not support "launch the intent with result", which I am interpreting as meaning `startActivityForResult()`. As [the `ACTION_EDIT` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EDIT) states, there is no output. Just use `startActivity()`.

Beyond that, you are the one who provided the `Uri` in the `Intent` for the editor, so at that point in time, you already knew what the `Uri` was that you handed to the editor. Hang onto that `Uri` in your saved instance state, so that you can ensure that you have the `Uri` even if Android terminates your process while the user is editing the image. While there is no requirement that an `ACTION_EDIT` `Intent` save the edited image back to the location specified by the `Uri` used to load the image, one hopes that most `ACTION_EDIT` activities do just that.