# Android image edit intent: retrieving saved file location

Tags: android

Following [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640029/android-image-editor-intent-retrieving-saved-file-location), how can I retrieve the image generated by edit intent if it was not saved to the same uri as the orignal image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible, sorry. You have no way of knowing if the other app saved its content to some other location.